# Weird Windows 10 behavior

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm running Windows 10 for the last few months. However, since 3 days, I'm experiencing some weird behavior. Everything works fine for 4-5 minutes, but once I start the laptop, multiple windows open if you click on the Taskbar (e.g. if Chrome is open, then the new window of Chrome will open), and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaves in Right to Left window order etc.

I did a full scan with NOD32 AV, but nothing was detected. Also, when restarting, I'm getting this screen:

[image: Snap-1]

[Snap-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IgNd.jpg)

Is it some virus?
Or is it due to any windows update? I'm unable to figure it out.
Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: It says it needs a Repair. Open Windows Defender, Threat section and do a full scan. When done, do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with.   
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Does your system currently even boot?  Whenever I have received the message in your second screenshot, it mean the storage device had failed, and Windows could not be repaired.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes it boots and everything works fine for 4-5 minutes. Then the weird behaviour starts.

Comment: @John - I have done full scan today; nothing was detected. Will the Repair install remove all the programs?

Comment: Keep Everything does just that - Keeps programs and data. Back up data just to be sure.

Comment: I wonder why everything works fine for 5-7 minutes and after that some files are replaced automatically which is causing problem. I also ran sfc /scannow

Comment: reset done using keep everything but it did not solve the problem. also, when trying to type numbers, the corresponding character is typed (without using shift). can this be some program/language input issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the computer thinks the Shift key is pressed down.
There may be something wrong with one of the Shift keys on your keyboard.
I would remove their keycaps, ensure they are not pressed down, and see if the behaviour continues. Maybe pressing them a bunch of times will get them unstuck.

The boot options screen shows when you press and hold down the Shift key at boot. Alt-Tab goes in the reverse direction if you hold Shift. If Chrome is open and you Shift-click the Chrome icon in the taskbar it will open a new window.

It is not a virus. It is not caused by a Windows update.

The easiest way to check if this is the case is probably to start the on-screen keyboard.

https://www.howtogeek.com/240288/how-to-use-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-windows-7-8-and-10/